# What does the iOS Simulator’s “Motion Control” menu item do?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, apple-m7

In the iOS Simulator that ships with Xcode 5, there is a menu item **Window → Motion Control**. Clicking it seems to have no effect. Does anyone know what it does? Is it related to either the M7 coprocessor on recent iOS devices, or the “Switch Control” accessibility feature?

Comment: It would be super neat to have motion control be moving the window to simulate the gyro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can’t be sure what it does, but I disassembled the iOS Simulator MainMenu.nib using [NibUnlocker](http://www.charlessoft.com), and that menu item sends a method called `-showMotionControl:` to the `GuiController` class. My best guess is that it is related to an Apple internal feature that never shipped. Perhaps a way to simulate gyro and/or accelerometer values?

Answer (score 0):

This menu item was **only visible in early beta versions of Xcode 5.1** and has been dropped in Xcode 5.1 beta 4.

So I presume that this feature won't be shipped with the final version of Xcode 5.1 and that's why we never got to use it.